# MSSQL: How do I run the extended stored procedure xp_fileexist remotely?

Tags: sql-server, procedure

Is there any way I can achieve this? I have full control over the local and the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you trying to execute xp_fileexist with a network path to access a remote server for example:

`exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist "\\another_server\path\file"`

The main reason if you can't do it - Your SQLSERVER service is running under the LOCALSYSTEM account. This account is a local computer account and [has no access to network](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/services/understanding-the-local-service-and-network-service-accounts) (though as I know [there is a way to grant access](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/howt-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account) to share folder on server2 to localsystem from server1 account). So If you configure your SQL server service to run under DOMIAN\USER you can run above command and get right results. Also beware if you run your SQL server under domain account it will be a hole in your domain security system as soon if a user has access to your SQL server it can remotely execute XP_CMDSHELL ....

I just tested it under SQL server 2000 running under localsystem and then reconfigured to run under domain account.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as any other SP. But please note that you will get data only about remote files. If you need data about local files you can't do it on the SQL Server side. You need to check it on the client side and (if you need to use these data on the server side) send it to SQL Server as parameters.